# Rspec have_link with accent words

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, tdd, rspec2

Anyone experienced this kind of test?

Doing this:

```
# this works
it { should have_link("Next") }
```

but the same test using a word that contain accents like "Próximo" (means Next in portuguese)

```
# it fails
it { should have_link("Próximo")  }
```

**error:**

```
1) UserPages index pagination 
     Failure/Error: it { should have_link("Próximo") }
       expected link "Próximo" to return something
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:29:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 2.8 seconds
28 examples, 1 failure
```

**user_pages_spec.rb** (only the relevant code)

```
describe "pagination" do
  before(:all) { 30.times { FactoryGirl.create(:user) } }
  after(:all) { User.delete_all }

  it { should_not have_link('delete') }
  it { should have_link("Próximo") }
  it { should have_link('2') }
end
```

How should I do this test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed.

For a moment I forgot that I was running under Spork and all I have to do was restart the webserver and restart the Spork as well.

**Tip:** If you are running Nginx, go to console and type `touch tmp/restart.txt` under your project folder. It will restart the Nginx.

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to put:

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

at the top of your spec file so Ruby knows the file contains non-ASCII characters.

more info: http://nuclearsquid.com/writings/ruby-1-9-encodings/

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using? With Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2, RSpec 2.8 and that comment I just tried out `it { should have_link("Próximo")  }` on a page and it passed.

Comment: rails 3.2.1, ruby 1.9.2p290 and rspec 2.8.1 - it fails

Comment: @KleberS. could fix it by upgrading to Ruby 1.9.3? A pragmatic workaround might be to just test for regexp /ximo/ if have_link supports that

Answer (score 2):

Does your source specify that the script has Unicode in it?

```
# encoding: UTF-8
```

Here is a really good writeup: http://yehudakatz.com/2010/05/05/ruby-1-9-encodings-a-primer-and-the-solution-for-rails/